# What is the pointer of bool datatype?

Tags: c, function, return, boolean

Actually I came across a problem where I want to print the return value of a function but it is true or false. SO, how can I point out a bool.

For example, %c = for char
%i = for integer
but what is for bool type

```
 bool s = valid_triangle(x, y, z);

printf("%u\n",s);
return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why does your title ask about a “pointer”? Did you mean to ask something about “printing”? A correct title could be “What printf conversion specifier should be used for bool?”

Answer (score 0):

In C the name `bool` is an alias of the type `_Bool`. It is an integer type. You may use for example the  conversion specifier `d` or `i` to output either 1 or 0 of an object of the type `bool` due to the integer conversions because the rank of the type `_Bool` is less than the rank of the type `int`..